# How much space taken when using System.Linq?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, unity-game-engine

Linq functions on `List<T>` are awesome, however, in this particular file I'm working on there are only 1 line that use it. So I wanted to know how much space this library took upon importing for use? (I'm using the `First` function.)

If it's taking too much space then it would make sense to create a custom `for` loop to iterate through instead. But my code is cleaner when using Linq.

For memory usage I think using Linq and using `for` don't really make that much difference so I want to know disk space usage if I would use it in Unity3D on mobile devices. If anyone can provide a way to determine disk size of any System library it would be very useful!

Comment: Why do you care? Do you have any requirements about disk space usage? If you do, using the whole .net framework doesn't seem like the best choice anyway...

Comment: Create a version with LinQ and one without and test it?

Comment: If it is taking much disk space than I thought then, yes, I care. I don't know if it's taking much or not because Linq seemed like a really big thing.

Using .NET is a must because I'm developing mobile games in Unity (C#) and I wanted to reduce as much download time as possible.

Comment: @Sargon: Its quite important that you add Unity/Android to your question as this seems to be a critical difference to the answer you would get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET framework is installed on your computer. Its not linked into your .exe binary. Its only referenced, which is quite a difference.

Edit:

In followup to Baldricks question, on mobile devices using Unity there should be taken extra care about additional dependencies. They will get **bundled** into the "player" and add to download size.

> Remove unnecessary code dependencies.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

On the other hand LINQ requires `System.Core.dll` which is an essential for .NET applications. So your bets are high that its already included and LINQ doesn't add to existing download size.

Comment: Is this always true? On Windows with MS framework, maybe. But I'm not so sure it's the same with Unity. If you download a Unity game onto your Android device, and it uses C#, it's quite possible it would transfer only a subset of the Mono Framework depending on what's used. In that case, is it not possible that referencing more assemblies might increase the disk space used?

Comment: Its still not bundled into your binary. If there's a dependency and that dependency is not yet installed on your device I guess it will be downloaded and installed. But I don't know Android well in this regard. Doesn't change the fact that it only uses libraries installed on your system.

Comment: From what I understand from Unity, it packages your game with all needed dependencies so you have a single game 'install package' (per platform published). So I would assume Unity knows that Android has no native .Net library and adds the needed DLLs. But as LINQ is part of the System.Core DLL, I would assume it'll always be included regardless, since the Core will be needed for general .Net operations.

Comment: @Flater: So the conclusion is that using LINQ shouldn't make any difference, but using more obscure parts of .NET *might*.

Comment: @Baldrick: Unless Unity has a very different idea of publishing a game; yes.

Comment: @BlueM I don't think it is essential. If you write everything yourself you may manage to live without System.Core. But if you use any other libraries (incl. other .net libraries) they might require System.Core.

Answer (score 7):

`using` directive doesn't really import anything into the application. It is merely language construct for using namespaces. What is really important if the assembly is actually included into the build. [Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX):

> Namespace:  System.Linq
>
> Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

So what really matters is if this assembly is included. And yes, it is included by default in common assemblies that are installed in the system, so by just using Linq you don't make your file bigger.

**Edit:** question appeared to be in light of mono and Unity. In theory you can build .net app without using `System.Core.dll` if you are not using external libraries (and some of .net's). But very likely that other libraries that you have to use depend on it. Now regarding mono, it looks like mono treats `System.Core` as special assembly and it is not necessary to reference it, it is done automatically apparently:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace t1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

builds just like that `dmcs Program.cs`. Also if you create empty solution in Xamarin studio it also works and only `System.dll` is in references.

Answer (score 1):

The using directive will just refer to the existing .Net Framework in the computer. It wont always result into directly linking or pulling the assembly in your build.
Referenced assemblies do lead to size growths.
But, however, the using directive does not tell the compiler to include referenced assemblies.
By referencing them in the project, however, you're telling the csc compiler where to find the assembly to link to when compiling. 
So the assemblies are not referenced unless I reference them via the project or unless they are actually referenced in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried on version 2020.1 of **unity** and the build size doesn't change after using a function inside linq.

So there is no impact.